# Can you get rid of the "Microsoft Office Excel has encountered a problem" dialog?

Tags: windows, excel, crash, ms-office

You know the one I mean:

[image: Excel has crashed... again!]

Is there a way to disable this?

I'm writing an application to automatically test a large number of Excel spreadsheets which are used in a critical environment. Many of these sheets do crazy things which crash Excel. When Excel crashes I want it to terminate ASAP and without user-intervention.

- I definitely do not want to re-start excel.
- I do not want the excel.exe process to hang-around waiting for somebody to click on "Don't Send"
- And I **never never** want to report the details of my crash to Microsoft!

Comment: Excel in a critical environment?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It a system service that you can easily turn off

[Turn off Error Reporting in Microsoft Windows XP Professional](https://web.archive.org/web/1/http://articles.techrepublic%2ecom%2ecom/5100-10878_11-5276398.html)

If that doesn't work go to Control Panel / Admin tools / Services and stop and disable the "Error Reporting Service"

Answer (score 1):

Can you somehow detect that Excel has crashed? You can use `TerminateProcess` function after that, which removes the process for good. There's [an article](http://blogs.msdn.com/oldnewthing/archive/2004/07/22/191123.aspx) about it on Raymond Chen's blog.

Comment: Is there a difference between TerminateProcess and whatever taskkill.exe does?